# Estoy creando un sitio web con wordpress y PHP, y tengo un problema al hacer peticiones a la base de datos con GET dentro de una plantilla del tema

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy creando un sitio web con WordPress y PHP, y tengo un problema al hacer peticiones a la base de datos con GET dentro de una plantilla del tema. Si yo hago la misma petición con unos ficheros creados fuera del tema de WordPress si me funciona correctamente, pero necesito que esto se haga dentro del tema para que visualmente se corresponda con el resto de la web.

Concretamente lo que estoy intentando es crear dos selectores dinámicos, que en función de lo que seleccione en uno haga una petición y traiga los datos asociados a esa selección para rellenar el otro selector. El primer selector si se rellena bien pero el segundo selector no se rellena y da un 404 cuando intento hacer la petición

Primero voy a mostrar los ficheros que utilizo FUERA del tema y que si me funciona:

**index.php**

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
$db =  connect();
$query=$db->query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent in(SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id in(8,9))group by post_parent");
$events = array();
while($r=$query->fetch_object()){ $events[]=$r; }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Gestión de actividades</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrapsy.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<BR>

 <div class="container" >
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-12">

<h1>Gestión de actividades</h1>

</div>

</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-6">

<form method="post" action="attendant_list.php?opt=all">

  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="name1">Evento</label>

    <select id="post_title" class="form-control" name="post_title" required>

      <option value="">-- SELECCIONE --</option>

<?php foreach($events as $c):?>

      <option value="<?php echo $c->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $c->post_title; ?></option>

<?php endforeach; ?>

    </select>

  </div>



  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="name1">Fecha</label>

    <select id="event_id" class="form-control" name="event_id" required>

      <option value="">-- SELECCIONE --</option>

   </select>

  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Aceptar</button>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="panel-footer"></div>
</div><!-- /.Cierra-default-panel -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#post_title").change(function(){
            $.get("evento_fecha.php","post_title="+$("#post_title").val(), function(data){
                $("#event_id").html(data);
                console.log('data1 --> ' + data);
                console.log('post_title --> ' + post_title.value);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**evento_fecha.php**

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
$db=connect();
$query=$db->query("select post_parent, post_date from wp_posts where post_title like '$_GET[post_title]' and post_parent!=0 group by post_parent");

$dates = array();
while($r=$query->fetch_object()){ $dates[]=$r; }
if(count($dates)>0){
// print "<option value=''>-- SELECCIONE --</option>";
foreach ($dates as $s) {
    print "<option value='$s->post_parent'>$s->post_date</option>";
}
}else{
print "<option value=''>-- NO HAY DATOS --</option>";
}
?>
```

**conexion.php**

```
<?php
function connect(){
    return new mysqli("db","aula_redes_seguridad","aula_redes_seguridad","wordpress");
}
?>
```

Utilizando esto me queda el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora voy a mostrar los ficheros que utilizo para lo mismo pero dentro del tema astra de WordPress:

**plantillaGestionActividades.php**

```
<?php

/*
   Template Name: Plantilla Gestion Eventos
*/

get_header();
?>
    <div id="primary" <?php astra_primary_class(); ?>>

   <h1 style="text-align: center"> Gestión de actividades </h1>
   <br><br>

   <form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
        
      </br></br>
      
      <label style="display: inline; margin-right: 10px">Evento</label>

      <select id="post_title"class="form-control" style="display: inline" name="post_title" required>
         <option selected = "true" disabled="disabled" value="">-- Selecciona un evento --</option>
         <?php

         global $wpdb;
         $items = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent in(SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id in(8,9))group by post_parent");
               
         foreach ($items as $item) {
               echo("<option value='$item->post_title'>$item->post_title</option>)");
         }
      ?>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label style="display: inline-block; width: 80px">Fecha</label>
      <select id="event_id"  name="event_id" class="form-control" required>
         <option value="">Seleccione una fecha</option>
      </select>
      </div>
      </br></br>
      <input type="submit" name="honorariobtn" value="Consultar" />
   </form>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                  $("#post_title").change(function(){
                     $.get("cargarSelector.php","post_title="+$("#post_title").val(), function(data){
                        console.log('data 1 --> ' + data);
                        $("#event_id").html(data);
                        console.log('data 2--> ' + data);
                     });                                                             
                  });
});
</script>
```

**cargarSelector.php**

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
$db=connect();
$query=$db->query("select post_parent, post_date from wp_posts where post_title like '$_GET[post_title]' and post_parent!=0 group by post_parent");
$dates = array();
while($r=$query->fetch_object()){ $dates[]=$r; }
if(count($dates)>0){
// print "<option value=''>-- SELECCIONE --</option>";
foreach ($dates as $s) {
    print "<option value='$s->post_parent'>$s->post_date</option>";
}
}else{
print "<option value=''>-- NO HAY DATOS --</option>";
}
?>
```

**conexion.php**

```
<?php
function connect(){
    return new mysqli("db","aula_redes_seguridad","aula_redes_seguridad","wordpress");
}
?>
```

Y utilizando esto me queda el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Headers*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuál es la causa por la que no me carga el segundo selector cuando lo hago dentro de los ficheros del tema de WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error esta aquí

```
$.get("cargarSelector.php","post_title="+$("#post_title").val(), function(data){
    
});
```

Prueba a enviarle la url completa, sin embargo desconozco si eso te llegue a funcionar, WordPress funciona de forma diferente y suele bloquear ciertas peticiones si no se hacen de forma correcta como medida de seguridad, yo personalmente lo haría así:

Primero crearía una función llamada `cargarSelector()` y utilizaría el hook `wp_ajax_` para ejecutar la función por ajax, luego, como ya estas dentro de un Tema WordPress ignoraría la conexión y directamente llamara a la variable global `$wpdb;`, crearia el query y lo enviaría con `get_results()`, algo como esto.

```
function cargarSelector(){
    
    // Obtenemos la variable enviada
    $post_title = $_POST['post_title'];

    // Iniciamos la variable Global $wpdb
    global $wpdb;

    // Crearemos una variable a la cual haremos echo al final
    $html;

    // Creamos el Query
    $sql = "SELECT post_parent, post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE {$post_title} AND post_parent!=0 GROUP BY post_parent";

    // Enviamos el Query y obtenemos los resultados
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

    if ( $result ) {
        $html .= $result;
    }

    // Ya con el resultado puedes hacer lo que quieras y lo retornas con un echo
    print_r($html);

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_cargarSelector', 'cargarSelector' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cargarSelector', 'cargarSelector' );
```

Luego crearía una función para hacer la llamada a la accion anterior usando el archivo `admin-ajax.php`

```
function llamar_cargarSelector(){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // Detectamos cuando cambia el valor
    jQuery( 'select#post_title' ).change(function(){

        // Obtenemos el valor del Post Title
        var post_title = jQuery( 'select#post_title option:selected' ).val();

        // Enviamos la peticion
        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action : 'cargarSelector',
                post_title : post_title
            },
            success: function(result){
                
                // Mostramos el resultado
                console.log( result );

            }
        });

    });

});
</script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'llamar_cargarSelector' );
```

Ahora solo agrega o remueve código según necesites.

Este código no esta probado, así que no sabría decirte si funcionara correctamente, posiblemente tengas que hacer algunas correcciones, solo es algo que se me ocurrió mientras leía tu pregunta. Siendo sincero hay muchas otras formas de hacer esto, como en vez llamar a la base de datos usar mejor la función `get_post()` y crear un `nonce` de seguridad, recomendaría leer un poco mas la documentación para encontrar formas mas elegantes y seguras de hacerlo.

También comento que hay que hacer un echo del resultado al final, mi recomendación es que lo hagas en un JSON para tener mayor control de la respuesta, en mi ejemplo uso un `print_r()` solo como fines de prueba.

Comment: No funcionó ni el pasarle la URL completa, ni con el método del Hook de Ajax, ahora ni siquiera realizaba la petición :(

Comment: como dije, posiblemente debas hacer modificaciones, verificar bien los parametros y probar un rato el query, wordpress funciona diferente, por lo que debes ver que errores te da e irlos solucionando, aqui solo te puedo guiar como podrias hacerlo, mas no hacerlo porque no conozco el panorama completo.